# Different spectrogram between audio_ops and tf.contrib.signal

Tags: python, tensorflow, speech-recognition

I am trying to update the feature extraction pipeline of an speech command recognition model replacing the function `audio_ops.audio_spectrogram()` by `tf.contrib.signal.stft()`. I assumed that they were equivalent, but I am obtaining different spectrogram values with the same input audio. Could someone explain the relation between the two methods, or whether it is possible to obtain the same results using `tf.contrib.signal.stft()`?

My code:

1) `audio_ops` method:

```
from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops import audio_ops
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python.ops import io_ops

#WAV audio loader
wav_filename_placeholder_ = tf.placeholder(tf.string, [], name='wav_filename')
wav_loader = io_ops.read_file(wav_filename_placeholder_)
sample_rate = 16000
desired_samples = 16000 #1 sec audio
wav_decoder = audio_ops.decode_wav(wav_loader, desired_channels=1, desired_samples=desired_samples)

#Computing the spectrograms
spectrogram = audio_ops.audio_spectrogram(wav_decoder.audio,
                                              window_size=320,
                                              stride=160,
                                              magnitude_squared=False)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    feed_dict={wav_filename_placeholder_:"/<folder_path>/audio_sample.wav"}
    #Get the input audio and the spectrogram
    audio_ops_wav_decoder_audio, audio_ops_spectrogram = sess.run([wav_decoder.audio, spectrogram], feed_dict)
```

2) `tf.contrib.signal` method:

```
#Input WAV audio (will be initialized with the same audio signal: wav_decoder.audio )
signals = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None])

#Compute the spectrograms and get the absolute values
stfts = tf.contrib.signal.stft(signals, 
                               frame_length=320, 
                               frame_step=160, 
                               fft_length=512, 
                               window_fn=None)
magnitude_spectrograms = tf.abs(stfts)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    feed_dict = {signals : audio_ops_wav_decoder_audio.reshape(1,16000)}
    tf_original, tf_stfts, tf_spectrogram, = sess.run([signals, stfts, magnitude_spectrograms], feed_dict)
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: window_fn=None is a bad idea when you want to match both. Default window is hanning

Comment: Thanks Nikolay, that was the bug, using default window I obtain the same spectogram. Would you know how to match also the output of `audio_ops.mfcc` using the `contrib.signal` approach? I followed the tutorial provided in https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/contrib.signal but I did not manage to match the outputs of the final MFCC coefficients.

Comment: Im also getting difference between audio_ops.mfcc and contrib.signal, did anyone find out what causes the difference?

Answer (score 3):

Found these helpful comments in github that discuss the differences:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11339#issuecomment-345741527

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11339#issuecomment-443553788

> You can think of audio_ops.audio_spectrogram and audio_ops.mfcc as
>   "fused" ops (like fused batch-norm or fused LSTM cells that TensorFlow
>   has) for the ops in tf.contrib.signal. I think the original motivation
>   of them was that a fused op makes it easier to provide mobile support.
>   I think long term it would be nice if we removed them and provided
>   automatic fusing via XLA, or unified the API to match
>   tf.contrib.signal API, and provided fused keyword arguments to
>   tf.contrib.signal functions, like we do for
>   tf.layers.batch_normalization.
>
> audio_spectrogram is a C++ implementation of an STFT, while
>   tf.signal.stft uses TensorFlow ops to compute the STFT (and thus has
>   CPU, GPU and TPU support).
>
> The main cause of difference between them is that audio_spectrogram
>   uses fft2d to compute FFTs while tf.contrib.signal.stft uses Eigen
>   (CPU), cuFFT (GPU), and XLA (TPU). There is another very minor
>   difference, which is that the default periodic Hann window used by
>   each is slightly different. tf.contrib.signal.stft follows
>   numpy/scipy's definition.